# Eclipse - custom text when hovering over a marker

Tags: java, c, eclipse, hover, markers

I working on an Eclipse plugin and currently I am trying to make Eclipse (Luna) to show customized text when hovering over a marker. I know that I could achieve this by specifying the marker arguments, but **I need to change the text dynamically**, e.g:

[image: Use case]

I have already tried these approaches **without** success:

1) Having a custom `TextEditor` with custom `SourceViewerConfiguration`:

```
public class MyEditor extends TextEditor {

    public MyEditor() {
        setSourceViewerConfiguration(new SourceViewerConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public IAnnotationHover getAnnotationHover(ISourceViewer sourceViewer) {
                return new IAnnotationHover() {
                    @Override
                    public String getHoverInfo(ISourceViewer sv, int ln) {
                        return "Hello world!";
                    }
                };
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the plugin.xml like this:

```
<extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
    <editor
            id="test"
            name="MyEditor"
            extensions="c"
            class="foo.bar.editors.MyEditor">
    </editor>
</extension>
```

My method **getHoverInfo** is never called. Instead, the method **getHoverInfo** from the **DefaultAnnotationHover** is being called any time I open any *.c file and hover over the marker. I checked the available editors via the Eclipse->Preferences->General->Editors and the `MyEditor` is there.

2) Adding the custom annotation hover dynamically. I found [here](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Feditors_hover.htm) information that it is possible. So every time I open a "*.c" file, I have this code:

```
IPartListener2 partListener2 = new IPartListener2() {
    @Override
    public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
            if ("org.eclipse.cdt.ui.editor.CEditor".equals(((EditorReference) partRef).getDescriptor().getId())) {
                CEditor currentCFileEditor = ((CEditor)((EditorReference) partRef).getEditor(false));
                currentCFileEditor.getViewer().setAnnotationHover(new IAnnotationHover() {
                    @Override
                    public String getHoverInfo(ISourceViewer sourceViewer, int lineNumber) {
                        return "Hello world";
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

But again, I was not successful - my `getHoverInfo` is not called at all.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who have a similar problem - I have found a "hacky" solution. I have created my own class `MyAwesomeHover`:

```
public class MyAwesomeHover implements IAnnotationHover {
    @Override
    public String getHoverInfo(ISourceViewer sw, int ln) {
        return "Hey hoo"
    }   
}
```

And then I use the reflection to set `MyAweseomeHover` as the displayed `AnnotationHover`.

```
    Field hm= SourceViewer.class.getDeclaredField("fVerticalRulerHoveringController");
    hm.setAccessible(true);
    AnnotationBarHoverManager ma= (AnnotationBarHoverManager) hm.get(sourceViewer);
    Field ah= AnnotationBarHoverManager.class.getDeclaredField("fAnnotationHover");
    ah.setAccessible(true);
    ah.set(ma, MyAwesomeHover());
```

Comment: With Eclipse Neon3, in order to get this fix working one has to disable the "Expand vertical ruler icons upon hovering (does not affect open editors)" option inside the preferences.