# Showing link inside custom hover (Eclipse plugin development)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hover, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt

I have a custom hover inside CDT editor (see the linked SO question) and now I want to show link inside my `IAnnotationHover` hover:

```
public class MyAwesomeHover implements IAnnotationHover {
    @Override
    public String getHoverInfo(ISourceViewer sw, int ln) {
        return "<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>so</a>"
    }   
}
```

Unfortunately the link is not shown - the hover window shows only simple text (i.e "so"). Other HTML elements I tried work OK (ul, li, p, font ...). Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445377/eclipse-custom-text-when-hovering-over-a-marker

Comment: Did you have a look at `RevisionHover`? It implements `IAnnotationHoverExtension` and `IInformationProviderExtension2` to show a custom hover control.

Comment: It is probably using the JFace `HTMLTextPresenter` which only supports a limited subset of HTML not including `<a>`.

Comment: Thanks guys, especially @Rüdiger Herrmann for the tip! I made it working via the IAnnotationHoverExtension. I will post an answer with my solution later here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments, the `RevisionHover` was a good starting point. The magic is in implementing the `IAnnotationHoverExtension` and creation of a custom  `AbstractReusableInformationControlCreator`. I am posting a code snippet with solution that worked for me.

```
public class MyHover implements IAnnotationHover, IAnnotationHoverExtension {
...
    @Override
    public IInformationControlCreator getHoverControlCreator() {
        return new MyCreator();
    }
...
    @Override
    public Object getHoverInfo(ISourceViewer sv, ILineRange lr, int vnl) {
        return "<a href='www.stackoverflow.com'>so</a>";
    }
...
   private final class MyCreator extends AbstractReusableInformationControlCreator {

        protected IInformationControl doCreateInformationControl(Shell parent) {

                BrowserInformationControl control = 
                                    new BrowserInformationControl(
                                        parent, 
                                        JFaceResources.DIALOG_FONT, 
                                        false);
                control.addLocationListener(
                                    new LocationAdapter() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void changing(LocationEvent ev) {
                                            if (ev.location.startsWith("file:")) {
                                                // !This opens the link!
                                                openUrl(ev.location)    
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                return control;
        }
    }
}
```